# Term for exaggerations such as "always", "never", "constantly", and so on

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I believe there is a term for words such as *never*, *always*, *constantly*, and so forth; words that generally exaggerate the situation being described. Unfortunately, I can't recall what that term is if I am correct in that there is indeed such a term. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "exaggerate"?  Are you referring to [hyperbole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole), in which case the words could be said to be _hyperbolic_, _hyperbolical_, or _hyperbolism_.

Comment: These words are not necessarily indicative of exaggeration. The Q. is therefore ambiguous. Do you want a class name for these words? Do you want a name for words used for exaggeration?

Comment: I believe that _never_, _always_, _constantly_ are all temporal adverbs or perhaps I should say frequency adverbs. They are not used for exaggeration or hyperbole. However, you might say they are used for emphasis as they categorically state how often something happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word describes our habit to use extremes in language, and what are its implications?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64754/what-word-describes-our-habit-to-use-extremes-in-language-and-what-are-its-impl)

Comment: False absolutism?

Overemphasis?

Overgeneralization?

Answer (score 3):

For a single word, consider *extremes* or *absolutes*. In some contexts, it may sound better to use the adjective form: *extreme words*, *absolute terms*, etc.

Comment: I think _absolutes_ is probably what is being looked for here and it is rare that absolutes are not exaggeration.

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding the answer you're after, but I have a friend who chastises me for making *blanket generalizations* whenever I use a word like *never* or *always* in a sentence. (He's a smart guy.)  Is that the phrase you're looking for?

In this case *generalization* means to make general or broad statements (often impossibly broad). Sometimes people also call these *blanket statements.*

Answer (score 3):

maybe you are thinking of "hyperbole", an obvious exaggeration intended to create a strong impression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any term other than 'time adverbs' is required to describe them, even if one exists.